# I can't call a method in the client from my LinkedList class

Tags: java, singly-linked-list, listiterator

got it working, see comments.

well apparently it's not just in the client. I can't call any of the methods I've created at all. For my assignment, I'm supposed to create those methods in a class then implement them in a client. I can't even call the methods within the initial class. Not sure why.

import java.util.*;

```
public class Driver5
{
  public static final int SENTINEL = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int value = 1;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<Intcoll5> P = new LinkedList<Intcoll5>();

    while(value != SENTINEL)
    {
      if (value > 0)
      {
        P.**insert**(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

still working on some methods, just trying to call insert()

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;

public class Intcoll5
{

  LinkedList<Integer> c = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  ListIterator<Integer> I = c.listIterator();

  public Intcoll5(int i)
  {
    c = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  }

  public void insert(int i)
  {
    Integer I = new Integer(i);
    if (!c.contains(I))
    {
      c.addFirst(I);
    }
  }

  public void copy(Intcoll5 obj)
  {

    while (I.hasNext())
    {
    }
  }

  public boolean belongs(Integer i)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public void omit(Integer i)
  {
    if (c.contains(i))
    {
      c.remove(i);
    }
  }

  public int get_howmany()
  {
    int i = 0;
    while (I.hasNext())
    {
      i++;
    }
    return i;
  }

  public void print()
  {
    while (I.hasNext())
    {
      Integer n = I.next();
      System.out.println(n.intValue());
    }
  }

  public boolean equals(Intcoll5 obj)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

just "insert" is underlined in the client, error is: "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 1):

There is no `insert` method in the `LinkedList` class.

Just use `add`.

```
if (value > 0) {
   Intcoll5 object = new Intcall5();
   object.insert(value);
   P.add(object);
}
```

I believe you're trying to invoke the `Intcoll5#insert()` method, but for this you will need to **refer** an instance of the `Incoll5` class. Note that your `P` object refers a `LinkedList`.

Also, the constructor of the `Intcoll5` class seem pretty weird to me, since it doesn't use it's `i` parameter. Change it to:

```
public Intcoll5()
{
   c = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}
```

Comment: so if I want to implement the class into the client how would I do so? Because I have that insert method there, so how do I call it in the client? Thanks.

Comment: `Intcoll5` represents a list of integers.  `LinkedList<Intcoll5>` is a list of `Intcoll5` and is therefore a _list of lists_.  Are you sure that's what you want?  If it is, then it looks like you want to insert an integer into _one_ of the lists of integers, but which one?

Comment: My teacher put this parameter here: 

    public Intcoll5(int i)
      {
        c = new LinkedList<Integer>();
      }

and I'm not sure why. it's making it hard to create the obj as I need an initial value to pass to it and I have no idea what to pass to it. I think if I pass any value to it initially it will take it as that number has been entered in the list.

Comment: Well...the parameter is completely redundant, since it's not used in the scope of the constructor.

Comment: I got rid of the parameter for now and emailed my teacher to ask him what the purpose of it is. I used kocko's suggestion and it worked.